# MFC CFileDialog open only select files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Using CFileDialog as a file open, I need to allow the user to only select a file that is displayed in the dialog list area, such as by clicking on it. We don't want the user to be able to type in a name in the File Name control. The OPENFILENAME (OFN) struct has several different flags (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms646839%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but I don't see one that prevents the user from typing in a filename.

The closest thing I saw was OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST, but that only specifies that the file exists; it still allows the user to type in a name.

Is there any way to do this without inheriting a new class?

**MORE INFO**

We need to prevent them from typing in a filename because they could open an inappropriate one. With the `lpszFilter` parameter, we filter the filenames so it only displays files with *ABC* in the filename (not the extension). So if they typed in a filename, they could enter something like `myCoolFileDEF.ext`. If the file exists, it will go ahead and let them open it (the dialog will close w/o an error message) even though they were only supposed to open files with *ABC* in the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using MFC, just [inherit a CFileDialog and disable the file name edit control and combobox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kbfsahf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I don't see the point of using CFileDialog AND writing another OFNHookProc callback, though you could start from [GetOpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

As a previous answer notes, you could root around in the dialog for the filename control and disable it. This is not without penalty though - if you turn on the CFileDialog hook callback logic, you get the "old style" file dialog on Vista and above, not the "new style" one. The "new style" file dialog is a lot more restrictive in what can be customized, and, as far as I know, doesn't provide a supported way to get at the filename control.

Reading your question, my first instinct is that you're over-designing your solution: if you supply a filter then the user has to go to quite a lot of trouble to select the wrong sort of file, and most users won't do that. If they do, it's possible that the user knows better than your program. If it were me, I would just use a filter, then after the file dialog has closed, check the returned filename - if it doesn't match the required pattern, I'd put up a message dialog to ask if the user if they're really sure, and open the file anyway if they insist that they are.

Comment: I agree - you beat me to the answer though! By putting the validation logic *after* the filename prompt, you can also reuse it e.g. to validate a filename supplied on a command line or via drag-and-drop.